# Jmeter using LoopCount instead of the ThreadNum variable(to save variable for every count and use it in another request)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am setting my Jmeter variable using this using beanshell assertion:

```
${__setProperty(id_${__threadNum},${id},)}
```

And using this in another request like this:

```
${__P(id_${__threadNum},)}
```

and running the requests like this

[image]

However I want to run the loop count instead of the thread. So that i can run the request one by one. How can i change it to so it is loopNum instead of the thread

Can i use this below when i want to use the loop instead of the thread??

I am setting my Jmeter variable using this:

```
${__setProperty(id_${__iterationNum},${id},)}
```

And using this in another request like this:

```
${__P(id_${__iterationNum},)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting the current iteration (1st loop - `1`, 2nd loop - `2`, etc.):

```
props.put("id_" + vars.getIteration(), vars.get("id"));
```

For getting all iterations (each time it will return `10`)

```
props.put("id_" + ctx.getThreadGroup().getSamplerController().getProperty("LoopController.loops"), vars.get("id"));
```

Few more hints:

1. Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into Scripts, either use "Parameters" section or go for code-based equivalents instead, like in my above examples `props` stand for JMeter Properties, `vars` - for JMeter Variables, etc.), see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details.
2. Don't use Beanshell for scripting, [since JMeter 3.1 you are supposed to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)

Comment: But how do i use this in the next request?

Comment: `${__groovy(props.get("id_" + vars.getIteration()),)}`

Comment: for example if i want to use it in a GET request should i use it like this? - /devices/${__groovy(props.get("id_" + vars.getIteration()),)

Comment: Oui, exactement